# How to filter a list with another list in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm racking my head how to filter a list of SharePoint Online (SPO) sites from a list of sites to skip.

```
$GroupSites = Get-SPOSite -Template "GROUP" -limit ALL -includepersonalsite $False | Select-Object URL
$ExemptURL = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\SiteExceptions.txt"

ForEach ($GroupURL in $GroupSites) {
if ($GroupURL -like "*$ExemptURL*") { Write-Host "Skipping $GroupURL" }
else { Remove-SPOUser -Site $GSiteUrl -LoginName $UserLoginID }
```

The issue I encounter is because the $ExemptURL is a list nothing ends up matching, I tried nesting a
`foreach ($Eurl in $ExemptURL)`
But this means it will write that it has skipped it but then it still removes it further in the script so
Also have tried using
`Where-Object` combinations without any success as I encountered the same issue where it looks at the all Exempt URLs not inspecting each one against the current $GroupURL in the ForEach sequence from $GroupSites list.

I'm stuck how to accomplish skipping specific URLs to skip and not have the script remove or not have any matches and remove from none or remove from all. Hope that makes sense trying to articulate this has troubled me too.
Have searched around couldn't find anything that matched in terms of having a list and filtering from another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if regex has an upper limit for filter length, but you could totally regex escape all of the exempt urls and join them with pipes so it would try to match any of them, and use that. You probably want to expand the URL on your first command, not just select it. Otherwise you end up with a bunch of objects with just the URL property, instead of a bunch of strings.

```
$GroupSites = Get-SPOSite -Template "GROUP" -limit ALL -includepersonalsite $False | Select-Object -Expand URL
$ExemptURL = (Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\SiteExceptions.txt"|ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

ForEach ($GroupURL in $GroupSites) {
    if ($GroupURL -match $ExemptURL) { Write-Host "Skipping $GroupURL" }
    else { Remove-SPOUser -Site $GSiteUrl -LoginName $UserLoginID }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand regex bit but this has been a really simple solution that keeps the script clean thank you very much for the quick response! I also realised in my script when I had it write the log that it had removed it was at the end of the ForEach which also caused it to say it was removed but may not have actually removed from exempted site regardless you provided a answer that works and very thankful - thank you @TheMadeTechnician !